# Can the curvature of a closed universe be measured?

Tags: astrophysics, cosmology, expansion, space-geometry

Suppose we were in a closed universe likened with a spherical surface such as that of the Earth's surface.

Assume also that the limits, represented by the limits of the observable universe, corresponds to a continent which would not have information from other continents.
Obviously the inhabitants of any continent could not send a light beam out to be observed coming back.

Is this a correct description of the real situation and are there other less dramatic experiments we might make to determine the universe’s possible curvature?

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand your argument, less your reasoning. Can you elaborate a bit more? You seem to describe some kind of though experiment, but to me big parts of that are missing. The curvature of the universe *has been* and *is being* measured...

Comment: @planetmaker My issue is simply how we can make determination about part of a universe - open or closed - outside its observable part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Friedmann equations of the ΛCDM model, the simplest way to get to know the curvature of the universe is to measure the density of the universe:

- If the density coincides with the critical density, the universe is flat and infinite. The density ratio, defined as the ratio of the measured density to the critical density, is then $\Omega=1$.
- If the density is less than the critical density, the universe is hyperbolic and infinite. The density ratio is $\Omega < 1$.
- If the density is greater than the critical density, the universe is spherical and finite. The density ratio is $\Omega > 1$.

The best measurements we currently have of the **current density ratio** $\Omega_0$ are those made by the Planck Mission, the results of which are:

$$\Omega_0 = 0.9993 \pm 0.0019$$

Measurement that does not exclude any of the 3 possibilities. Source: [***Planck 2018 results. VI. Cosmological parameters***](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209)

***Imagine*** that the real density ratio of the universe was $\Omega_0 = 1.0012$ Then it would be a spherical universe, whose radius can be easily calculated by means of:

$$R=\dfrac c{H_0 \cdot \sqrt{\Omega - 1}}$$

$c=299792458$ m/s

According to the best value of the Planck Mission:

$H_0=67.66$ (km/s)Mpc

And with this hypothetical value of $\Omega_0=1.0012$ we would obtain that the universe would now have a radius of 417 billion light years.

Note that in this case, the maximum value of the density ratio provided by the error bar has been chosen for the calculation:

$\Omega_0=0.9993+0.0019=1.0012$

And therefore we have obtained the minimum possible value (according to Planck's measurements) of the radius of the Universe:

$R=417$ billion light years

As the radius of the Observable Universe is known to be 46.2 billion light years, we have obtained that, (again, according to the Planck Mission measurements), **the radius of the Total Universe is at least 9 times larger than the radius of the Observable Universe**.

Best regards.